# help Identification

Tags: components

[image]

Gentleman, I need help in identifying this component. There are 6 on the board but, this one and one other are black at the end. The rest have a very light blue stripe on the same end as the black on this one. The second picture of course are the "good ones", id like to know what they are and can I get them.

What I'm working on is a Kodak pulse 7inch picture frame.[image] enter image description here

Comment: Glass Diode????

Comment: Measure the resistance in both directions, check whether it is a diode by measuring forward voltage..

Comment: ok thank you, I realize some glass diode's have a black stripe, but this one looks bad to me, your thoughts.

Comment: Looks like a glass encapsulated diode to me. Though what kind of diode is indeterminate.

Comment: ok I will check be right back, again thank your for your help.

Comment: And yes, the one in the first image kind of looks like the smoke came out. You can test it with a multi-meter though. Check the forward and backward resistance. If they differ it's probably ok.

Comment: The  band colour difference may be a clue that one type is ordinary silicon diode, while the other might be a zener (avalanche) diode. Your ohmmeter tester likely won't discriminate as Trevor has suggested.

Comment: Are ladies allowed to reply?

Comment: 100 percent ladies reply, this thing has 2,300 pictures of my son on it id like to get it working

Comment: ok so I had to watch a video or 2, I'm a visual type. So just a follow up, I checked the 2 black diodes in question the one in the picture is only giving me a reading in one direction of .530, the other is giving me a reading in both directions .610 .540, this tells me something, got to figure out what it is telling me. I really appreciate all your help, if ya have anymore input please feel free to share.

Comment: @Optionparty: I've heard that diodes have a terminal that is called anode and one that is called cathode, ... but what is the "+ end"?

Comment: Chu I apologize, I just caught on, I meant nothing by my greeting.

Comment: @Curd... that depends if its a zener or a regular diode. A regular diode the + end is the anode. A zener goes the other way around. It's easy to remember, think of the symbol... it looks like a K. Cathode sounds like it starts with a K.. so pointy end is the cathode.

Comment: @Trevor: I know which terminal of a diode is the anode and which one is the cathode! The anode is the "+ end" only when the diode is currently conducting; not when it is blocking. And of course a diode is NOT always conducting because if that'd be the case you could just replace it by a piece of wire (assuming ideal diode; and excepting LEDs). What I wanted to point out is that it doesn't make sense to call one terminal the "+ end" when talking about diodes in general!

Comment: @curd :) Ya I was thinking that but I didn't want to say it in so many terms for fear of insulting you. Anyhoos... someone else might find it useful.

Comment: Well I might be new here ,  but I certainly found it interesting, as that it's right in line with some of the reading I've done today.

Comment: Answer: Cathode, sorry for creating so much confusion.

Answer (score 2):

Yup, certainly diodes.  Its even marked on the PCB, so thats good as it confirms it.  if they are blown, try replacing them with normal/leaded diodes to try it out before ordering surface mount ones.

Also, are there any markings on the PCB? You never know, you might be able to find a schematic for the whole board, that way you will know what sort of diodes they are :)

Comment: I noticed the diode sign just after I had post this, ill be honest I didn't know what it stood for, but I put my camera on a huge angle and saw them just tucked under it.  where would I go to find a schematic of the board.

Comment: " where would I go to find a schematic of the board." Start by finding a model number on the board, then Google. Or get the model and manufacturer of whatever the board comes from, and Google.

Answer (score 1):

[The ones with a blue band are probably Zener diodes.](http://www.marsport.org.uk/smd/sod80.htm)

There's not much else you can tell about them with no more information than you've got.

There are diodes with more information in the color code, those have more color bands.

Answer (score 1):

Those are diodes.  The package looks like what some manufacturers (I'm pretty sure Fairchild is one of them) refer to as "LL34".

These kinds of diodes are small signal or Zeners.

Comment: The package is also known as [MELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metal_electrode_leadless_face).