# A broken diode - is it fixed or not?

Tags: diodes

I recently noticed there is small diode (D2) broken next to the 1000uf capacitor. Can anyone tell me what kind of diode that could be? All I can tell it is blue with black stripe (see the top photo.)   What is the safest D2 diode I can put there instead? Or maybe it is already fixed with 0.2A1 one?
For some reference, this is a turntable that rotates too fast (when use 33.3 mode it rotates about 40rpm, 45 do about 50rpm) and I am trying to find the reason for that.

[image]

Comment: **can anyone tell me what kind of diode that could be?** a broken glass one. That's all we can say. That also precludes any possibility to recommend anything.

Comment: Is this by any chance a turntable with a 50Hz motor running off of 60Hz? (60Hz/50Hz = 1.2; 1.2 * 33.3rpm = 39.96rpm; 1.2 * 45rpm = 54rpm)

Comment: A 50Hz motor will run around 20% faster on a 60Hz power supply (same logic applies for 60Hz equipment on 50Hz power supply, 20% slower). Doing the math, the values that you specified are quite similar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regarding broken diode D2: It is possible that glass diode D2 was *deliberately* broken after assembly, because that was quicker than desoldering it (e.g. post-production modification by the manufacturer, before sale - I've seen similar things done during mass-production). Then the two-pin TO-92 package was soldered across its leads, as a replacement for D2.

I believe the TO-92 device *is* a replacement for the original glass diode D2, and therefore you do not need to replace the original glass diode D2.

Notice that if I am correct and the TO-92 device was added as a post-production modification (or *perhaps* a previous repair), it could be quickly soldered to the pins of the original diode D2 *without needing to remove the PCB from the chassis*, as long as the original D2 was physically destroyed (as it has been). (If the modification / repair procedure had required the original D2 to be carefully desoldered and removed, then the PCB would need to be removed from the chassis to do the desoldering, which takes longer and so costs more.)

In this situation, consider:

- Reverse-engineer at least some of that circuit, to better understand what part D2 plays in the circuit. If it's not involved with the motor speed, then it cannot be causing your  motor speed problem.

  Just as a guess (and without seeing the PCB tracks), that diode *might* be in series with nearby power resistor R1. If so, that is a classic arrangement for the diode being a zener diode, to create a (moderately) regulated power rail. Measure the voltage across D2 and see if it is a constant and sensible zener diode voltage, to give you more clues.

  A previous answer [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/291551/101852) linked to a [page](http://www.marsport.org.uk/smd/sod80.htm), suggesting a quasi-standard for some manufacturers that blue cathode lines (like on the remains of the original glass D2) can indicate a zener diode.

  Although you mentioned that the TO-92 device marking was "0.2 A1", I suggest that the markings could be "8.2 A1" and **8.2V is a standard zener diode voltage**. That might again be a clue that this TO-92 device is a zener diode, especially if you measure a constant 8.2V across it.
- You could also desolder one end of the TO-92 device which as been soldered across the original D2. Using a multimeter, check - is that a diode? If it is, then further investigation is *probably* a waste of time, as you would have confirmed that you do have a diode at location D2, except it's that TO-92 device, not the glass one.

If this turntable was working correctly, and then suddenly developed the speed fault, then I believe it was working correctly with the TO-92 replacement for D2, and you don't need to replace the original D2. That is not saying that the TO-92 replacement for D2 is working correctly or not. It is just addressing your question about the *original* broken D2 as not needing to be replaced.

As others have kindly pointed out in the comments, this could be just a case of using a device intended for 50Hz mains, on 60Hz mains instead. You will know whether that is a possibility, depending on whether this has worked correctly before on the mains frequency where you are.